# Is it possible to set up bots for BitCoin faucet websites?

Tags: python, automation, bots, bitcoin

I was looking at the BitCoin faucets and they all require you to fill in information repeatedly to earn a very small amount of BitCoin (like 10 satoshis). The amount earned is definitely not worth the effort considering 1 BTC = 100million satoshis. If Python bots are made, tailored to each of these websites to automatically fill the information required (according to the timers) in theory one could generate a good amount of money over time. So what I mean is, having 30-40 websites open and equally 30-40 bots for each website filling out the information and running for days at a time.

As an example, let's say each time your bot fills out the information required, you earn 10 satoshis and there is no delay timer on one particular website. If your bot fills out this information and submits it every 5 seconds then theoretically you can earn 120 satoshis per minute (10x12); 7200 satoshis per hour (120x60); 172800 satoshis per day (7200x24); and 1209600 satoshis per week (7x172800). This is just for one single bot; if several bots are running at once (let's say 20) then you can earn 24192000 satoshis per week which is actually not bad at all.

I am new to BitCoin and I am a Jr developer.

I am 100% sure that people have already thought of this idea, my question is: Can you please tell me what is wrong with this idea?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: if it's on the web probably there would be a `captcha` validation to prevent bots to **exploit** the service in the way you suggest

Answer (score -1):

I managed to create a bot for a popular site Faucet Crypto which is one of the high paying one, the bots developed with python and selenium thinking it might help you, here the link.

https://github.com/souravrs999/FaucetCryptoBot/blob/main/FaucetCryptoBot/fcbot.py